# ScrollView won't scroll after adding as subview

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

So i'm adding UIView with UIScrollView in it to another view by pressing segment tool:

UIView.h

```
@interface gettingELORolesViewController : UIViewController{
    UIViewController *currentController;
    NSMutableArray *viewControllers;
}
- (IBAction)SegmentToggle:(UISegmentedControl *)sender;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *containerView;
```

UIView.m

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard_iPhone"
                                                  bundle:nil];

 firstView *FirstView = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"firstOne"];
 secondView *SecondView = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"secondOne"];

 viewControllers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:FirstView,SecondView,nil];

 currentController = FirstView;

 [containerView addSubview:FirstView.view];//containerView = self.view
```

and then depends on what segment is chosen, it shows different view:

```
- (IBAction)SegmentToggle:(UISegmentedControl *)sender {
    UIViewController *selectedView=nil;

    if (sender.selectedSegmentIndex==0) {
        selectedView= [viewControllers objectAtIndex:0]; // retrieve object at index 0 from viewControllers array

    }
    else if(sender.selectedSegmentIndex==1){    
        selectedView= [viewControllers objectAtIndex:1]; // retrieve object at index 1 from viewControllers array

    }

    [currentController.view removeFromSuperview]; // remove Current displaying view from superView
    currentController=selectedView; // make selected View to be the current View
    [containerView addSubview:selectedView.view]; // Add newly selected view on container View
}
```

secondView is tableViewController and everything is working great when i choose second segment. When i choose first one it shows up but scroll doesn't work and i don't know why.

firstView.m viewDidLoad method looks like this:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    mainScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
    [mainScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 600)];
    [mainScrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
}
```

Paging is enabled in storyBoard. And it hooked up with .h file of firstView.
Please tell me what am i doing wrong.

Comment: Please post all the layout code of `firstView.m`. Are you actually calling `[self.view addSubview:mainScrollView];` ?

Comment: i'm updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `-SegmentToggle:`,

- you create a local variable called `selectedView`
- you assign a view controller to `selectedView` depending on what segment is selected
- the method ends, `selectedView` goes out of scope

In short, you're not doing anything. You should, at least, replace a view in the current view hierarchy with the view of the selected controller (and maybe stash a reference to the selected controller in an instance variable for later lookup?)

But taking a step back, it looks like you're trying to create a view controller that manages other view controllers. There are now very specific rules around that as of iOS 5. Please watch the [WWDC 2011 video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/) called "[Implementing UIViewController Containment](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/includes/implementing-uiviewcontroller-containment.html)" for more information and examples.

Comment: You don't show us how `currentController` is defined either, so we're kind of in the same boat. But regardless my advice is the same. Watch the video. There are several reasons you don't want to toss new managed subviews into a view that's is, itself, already managed by a controller. The video explains why and the right way to do it.

Comment: Or, if you're not the movie type, [here's a blog post](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/04/containing-viewcontrollers/) that goes over most of the same stuff.